# Abstracting away a generic type parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm running into a situation where I can't seem to avoid `any` in Typescript. Here's an example that mirrors what I'm trying to do:

```js
type NativeFn<A, B> = {
    kind: 'native'
    fn: (a: A) => B
}

type ComposeFn<A, B, C> = {
    kind: 'compose'
    f: Fn<B, C>
    g: Fn<A, B>
}

type Fn<A, B> = NativeFn<A, B>
    | ComposeFn<A, any, B>  // <=== HERE

function evalfn<A, B>(fn: Fn<A, B>, arg: A): B {
    switch (fn.kind) {
        case 'native': return fn.fn(arg)
        case 'compose': {
            // intermediate has type "any", which is a drag.
            const intermediate = evalfn(fn.g, arg)
            return evalfn(fn.f, intermediate)
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to say is that `ComposeFn<A, B, C>` is always a `Fn<A, C>`, no matter which type `B` is, but `B` should still be typed.

With `any`, I can incorrectly type things like:

```js
const F: Fn<string, string[]> = { kind: 'native', fn: (n) => [n] }

const G: Fn<number, number> = { kind: 'native', fn: (n) => n + 1 }

const FoG: Fn<number, string[]> = {
    kind: 'compose',
    f: F,
    g: G,
}
```

`unknown` doesn't work either. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgQxASwG5QGIDsA8BBAGhgCEA+GAXhgG9gZ6YBrZLAEwC4YByLJNKLnQYAzLJwAUCTngCUlcsWABfYKEiwAwgHsAthC0BnTLkIkiG8lVoMmLDtwDGu-UcE3hnbDmLnSQ+gDmniZEZMqq4NAwXqZklPB86DGhfjYAPjDaeobG+EQArliMWFoA7lgp9AD0VTA4FA0wABIAogBKLarChQ4oWlgwUKgIADaieSSk4qLBE2RECABOQTCynMQ0-jAGpcggDgAWMNNYAHTMbHLWNgwOCEbcvCjoXJyLUCD5iwOip6KSyxkWxsdweXCc2VcnGuNxuTiwBhAMBYICgix0UFYyCQsCoQ1G-1+AQWgOBsJgNWRWFR6Mx2NRMAO9xgkVgACIEFgwGyiKUDshDsiDDAEDBWIsEAFTmTYe9Pt9BsMxlgTn8iCi0RisTigeSYCobCoVMB4YjorNEYsWMTtiArVgAgBtAC6lk2Ngu9h4iQEBC2M2OWDkFHIjqwzr9xtNSIA4rMsPkdAAjNFES3Wt0w2xsTje56+-1iQPB8hcLgwADUMAq4RN-TNGC0ceiuATydTtvtTtd8SzntzEJcBfcnj9NhWMcjQA).

Is there any way do accomplish what I'm going for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not have direct support for [existential types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) (see [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)).  If it did, you would use an existential type like `<∃T> ComposeFn<string, T, number>` to mean something like "there is *some* type `T` such that my type is `ComposeFn<string, T, number>`, but I don't know or care what it is":

```
// not valid TS syntax, do not try this
type Fn<A, B> = NativeFn<A, B> | <∃T> ComposeFn<A, T, B>
```

---

Without direct support for such types, there are various workarounds.  The easiest one by far is to use `any` in place of the existential type and not worry too much.  Yes, this allows unsafe things to happen, but TypeScript isn't really a perfectly type-safe language (see [microsoft/TypeScript#9825](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825)) nor is it intended to be (see [TypeScript Design Non-Goal #3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals)) and `any` is really very convenient.

You might get a little extra safety by allowing `Fn` to specify the "existential" argument and having it *default* to `any`, like this:

```
type Fn<A, B, T = any> = NativeFn<A, B>
    | ComposeFn<A, T, B>

function evalfn<A, B, T>(fn: Fn<A, B, T>, arg: A): B {
    switch (fn.kind) {
        case 'native': return fn.fn(arg)
        case 'compose': {
            const intermediate = evalfn(fn.g, arg)
            return evalfn(fn.f, intermediate)
        }
    }
}
```

It's not perfect, but at least the compiler will complain instide `evalfn` if you do something too weird.

---

If you *really* want type safety, you can emulate existential types by using a generic function implementation; if I have a function signature like `<T>(x: T, y: T) => void` then the *caller* gets to choose `T` and the *implementer* needs to treat `T` like an existential type parameter.  By switching who's the caller and who's the implementer, it gives us a weird inside-out way to represent `Fn<A, B>` in a type-safe manner:

```
type SomeComposeFn<A, B> = {
  kind: 'compose',
  <R>(go: <T>(f: Fn<T, B>, g: Fn<A, T>) => R): R
}

type Fn<A, B> = NativeFn<A, B> | SomeComposeFn<A, B>
```

Here, a `SomeComposeFn<A, B>` is itself a function that acts sort of like a `Promise` for your `f` and `g` functions.  You can then implement `evalfn` like this:

```
function evalfn<A, B>(fn: Fn<A, B>, arg: A): B {
  switch (fn.kind) {
    case 'native': return fn.fn(arg)
    case 'compose': {
      return fn((f, g) => {
        const intermediate = evalfn(g, arg)
        return evalfn(f, intermediate)
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And if you have a value of your original `ComposeFn<A, T, B>` type, you can convert it into a `SomeComposeFn<A, B>` in a straightforward way, like resolving a promise:

```
function someComposeFn<A, T, B>(composeFn: ComposeFn<A, T, B>): SomeComposeFn<A, B> {
  return Object.assign(
    <R>(go: <T>(f: Fn<T, B>, g: Fn<A, T>) => R) => go(composeFn.f, composeFn.g),
    { kind: "compose" as const });
}
```

So that's perfectly type safe in just the way you want it, but cumbersome enough not to be the approach I'd probably choose.  Of course it's up to you, though.

---

Okay, hope that gives you some direction; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBYBPATEg3gKCUKQBd0ZkA5EYgSwDcIAxYAHhQBokAhAPiQF5cSAkVEBrGsAAmALiQByULQbyRowgDNgcgBQg5KAJQC+XNUgC+ec6XJIAwgHswMR1CasO3Tvb6D86kQS0nLy8M6u7qqBmnLMLFw+POaiAOZxnpy85lY2ZMjxXolIACoCSCAYfkhUyh5sWckxSAA+DhFu9V4ljdaiGgCuwPC0jsBIEHQgADZaDd6lPDpaGfPFJTycIABO6aiGcly4KURQAO40xPAAFkjLwAB0wVLGAc1E8CDuCkr0EPJybYQYgDbbjLQPLR6XaGE6BT7fMIdKJyN7vdThYBQYhISTECDbSBSGjUZCCSYzKEQ1JbGFw95AkFgiZTWbAe6Qzh4glEkn42HowhWZrCohWXKgSCwBDIACiAA8aNiIMBaDNjqJbJRqH9Co1ymj1M9Qr8VPSVnd9PsTNwcn0iFqkABlZwQJwuTp67jVQ3iSSyBThD1Rdj0lgAJSWqUcchYG2Wqx63s4ey9G2M-D44YOSHDdrydi9vHKtV1mW9rWdrvdkS6vXMg2Go3GFLZayWFqLmwquwMOaOvtOFyutw5z1e9NECOQih1KkBwNB4MeUJ2qQFgungeR-1Rk5ijKXSChyxTGb4g8FHzG2Nxqp5EGJpPKrahNJ76-36MPzNf7I0XL3oSj58hAG5XkKhgANxfpY9KikK9qEI6NaeuWxS+Aa9LGtuwb-OaqwYU0MSpuhxGIUhx5DCMNBjEgUDVjuaaNDoQa1swcioe4zHejmLqQFxdYVpeSA-uMADyABGABWEAjA8XxQDQqTsrBEZRjGSBxh2iaNCmqzdDw565sZ0asUxK6cGxaEPOuoZXjgSA4QARNZ7jORUUBIJit4WNB+Z4FYQA)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest simple thing, as you have union which has different arity of generics `NativeFn` has two arguments and `ComposeFn` has three, then the main one should also have three in order to not have a blank space, we can achieve that by default value of the third. Consider:

```
type Fn<A, B, C = B> = NativeFn<A, C>
  | ComposeFn<A, B, C>

function evalfn<A, B, C = B>(fn: Fn<A, B, C>, arg: A): C {
    switch (fn.kind) {
        case 'native': return fn.fn(arg)
        case 'compose': {
            const intermediate = evalfn(fn.g, arg)
            return evalfn(fn.f, intermediate)
        }
    }
}
```

What we did here:

- `Fn` has always three generic arguments. With default `C=B`
- `evalfn` also works with three argument generic types
- we change the return of `evalfn` to `C`

Lets check if it works correctly:

```
// my utility to make such construct
const makeNativeF = <A, B>(fn: (a: A) => B): NativeFn<A,B> => ({
  kind: 'native',
  fn
})
const nativeF = makeNativeF((a: number) => a);
const resultNative = evalfn(nativeF, 1); // correct number type result!

// my utility to make such construct
const makeComposeF = <A, B, C>(f: Fn<B,C>, g: Fn<A,B>): ComposeFn<A, B, C> => ({
  kind: 'compose',
  f,
  g
});

const composeF = makeComposeF(makeNativeF((a: number) => a + ': string'), makeNativeF((a: number) => a));
const resultComposed = evalfn(composeF, 1); // result is string! correct!
```

Everything looks good. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I just tried this out: [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=2#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgQxASwG5QGIDsA8BBAGhgCEA%20GAXhgG9gZ6YBrZLAEwC4YByLJNKLnQYAzLJwAUCTngCUlcsWABfYKEiwAwgHsAthC0BnTLkIkiG8lVoMmLDtwDGu-UcE3hnbDmLnSQ%20gDmniZEZMqq4NAwXqY%20MBqUMFgArgA2qZbwfOgxoX42AD7xzobG%20OZ59AD0VTA4FA0wABIAogBKLarCyVgOKFpYMFCoCKmi5SSk4qLBE2RECABOQTCynMQ0-jAGAO7IIA4AFjDTWAB0zGxy1jYMDghG3Lwo6Fyci1AgyYuDomeikmWMi2Nnujy4Tj0pTem1ucJgTiwBhAMBYICgix0UFYyCQsCow1GAL%20AQWQJB8JqqKw6Mx2Nx6JghweMEisAARAgsGB2UQdodkEdUQYYAgYKxFggAmcKXCPl8fkMRmMsKd-kQ0RisTi8cD4TAVDYVCpgIjkdFZsjFixSdsQNasAEANoAXUyN3ol3sPGyAgIWxmJywcgo5CdWBd-pNZpRAHFZikdAAjDFEK0291bL2cH0vP0BsRBkPkLhcGAAaiSUdUMeiWnj0VwiZTizT9ptrrbDoCmZs2ccJVc-vcnmHDBWsajQA)

Essentially I'm adding an optional Generic to `Fn` so that you can still only parameterize it with 2, but in the case you do parameterize it with 3, it uses the 3rd as the 2nd param for `ComposeFn` -- the return type of `g`.

Comment: No, because then the body of `ComposeFn` would need to take `f: Fn<B, C, D>, g: Fn<A, B, E>`. So we'd have to have `ComposeFn<A, B, C, D, E>`, and we'd be faced with the same problem we started with.

Comment: @hjfreyer I just edited my OG comment, hopefully this works. Let me know if it doesn't though. I find this problem extremely interesting, thanks for posting it!