# why can't you apply a union of things to a generic function that accepts each thing individually

Tags: typescript

i have a list of generic objects that i keep as a union because its helpful in other parts of my app, but i want to make helpers that are typed with a simpler structural type so they aren't affected by adding/removing things from the union.

a simple example looks like this:

```js
type BaseType = {[key: string]: string};

interface GenericInterface<T extends BaseType> {
  prop: T;
  func: (t: T) => void;
}

const thing1: GenericInterface<{one: string}> = {prop: {one: 'one'}, func: () => null};
const thing2: GenericInterface<{two: string}> = {prop: {two: 'two'}, func: () => null};

const genericFunction = <T extends BaseType>(input: GenericInterface<T>) => {
  return input;
};
const genericFunction2 = <G extends GenericInterface<BaseType>>(input: G) => {
  return input;
};

// these work, but this isn't what i'm trying to do
genericFunction(thing1);
genericFunction(thing2);

// these work if the interface doesn't have a function
genericFunction2(thing1); // error: Type 'BaseType' is not assignable to type '{ one: string; }'.
genericFunction2(thing2); // error: Type 'BaseType' is not assignable to type '{ two: string; }'.

const listOfThings = [thing1, thing2];

// i would like for this to work, but it doesn't
genericFunction(listOfThings[0]); // error: Type '{ two: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ one: string; }'.

// also works without the function
genericFunction2(listOfThings[0]); // error:  Type 'GenericInterface<{ one: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'GenericInterface<BaseType>'.
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Bllln+9JB9hQeOCezkJxoc4C0yQFrkozUOyfRAISi0ahwXUjaDAF2gSDnLBQMo7dIN1gtAB0Ffpom9EdmtejwcbKubdlbUFh0BancvPaNQwHUCHI7HE6nM-bLQXp2XdFXG4VGlPhGI1gAAeSEZAA1oIxMBwKNMm6BDZnoFweHjShNTsUZ9CgECCB6M9DSMacsO1PUDUoT43TzC4ty9as-RAsgIKg9IEBwAAGegjybcgWzbOcv2SLZf1of9ewfQcEGHUdx0nZ1kk-Bcl1ISo-ygNdN1eeM4BGBAXWTIwNiolJsM+VJoBuCN6LDJlfX3ZjwMg6COO43iT34s8SAvT9uTkXkszWRdmjU3ZVzMO8+0fZ85LfRTZyvfzlj5Yob3MDcgA)

`genericFunction` accepts each object individually, but once they are in a union it doesn't work.

`genericFunction2` would work for a simpler object, because the interfaces would extend one another, but here i run into an issue because functions with extensible args don't actually extend one another (i guess?).

i don't think there is any legitimate issue with the concept here, i think that if i can apply any member of a union i should be able to apply the union too, but from the errors it looks like its inferring the generic based on the first element of the union and validating the rest of the set against it. is there a way to get typescript to check each union member individually? or some other way to make this work?

in `genericFunction2` if i change it to use `G extends GenericInterface<any>` it works, but then inside the function the props will have the `any` type and will allow me to do things that i shouldn't based on the limitations of `BaseType`

Comment: What is "more specific" and "less specific" is backwards when dealing with functions.  A function that accepts a broader set of arguments `extends` one that accepts a subset of those arguments.  That's why you are getting errors with `genericFunction2`.

Comment: @linda-paiste i think i knew that... but i'm still wrapping my head around it. i think that means that no specific type will ever be able to extend a base type of my structure that has the generic value in both a prop and a function signature.

i think i'm working towards a plan to reorganize the structure so that it will work, but i still think the main issue i describe in my question is very confusing, possibly a bug. i would love some input from anyone who understands that issue with the union

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/kNrLoW) work for you?  I think your wanting unions to map to unions makes a bit more sense to me in this question, given that each element of the union also contains enough info to be useful (not just `func` but also `prop`).  TypeScript lacks [existential types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) which is really what you want (e.g., `<exists T extends BaseType>(input: GenericInterface<T>) => ...`) so we need to work around it

Comment: BTW, you can simulate existential types in TypeScript, which gives you [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmMJdW).  Basically you're saying a `SomeGenericInterface` has a pair of `func` and `prop` that go together but you cannot access the particular `T` from the outside.  You know that there is *some* `T` that works, but you cannot do anything with it.  All you can do is call `input.func(input.prop)`. Like [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403068/abstracting-away-a-generic-type-parameter-in-typescript).

Comment: jcalz, thats awesome, i'll try to adopt this pattern to hide my thing unions. i had gotten this far and was struggling to align the the constraints (passing in the function, passing in the args, and being able to call the function within the helper) https://tsplay.dev/VNVyvw

Comment: @jcalz is it possible to get the existential type back out without the callback? the way you have it implemented here makes flow control kind of awkward

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's the problem. TypeScript doesn't support existential types directly; you have to switch the control flow to emulate them, which is annoying.  If the only thing you ever do is `input.func(input.prop)` you could just make the callback do only that, as in [here](https://tsplay.dev/gWo39W).  Which if any of this do you want as your answer?  The distributed-union or the existential? Or both? (or neither)

Comment: i feel like the distributed union should work for me but i've found myself in a slightly more awkward position with another generic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/rw2xYm) and the same solution doesn't work in there so i may have to reorganize some things

Comment: i made that other function not a generic and now things seem to be looking up, the distributed union in the generic argument did it for me