# union of functions cannot be passed into generic function

Tags: typescript

```
// the function argument is important, if it was just an object argument it would work
const fn = <T extends {[key: string]: string}>(callback: (arg: T) => void) => undefined

// individual things
const thing1 = (arg: {key1: string}) => undefined
const thing2 = (arg: {key2: string}) => undefined

// union of either thing
const eitherThing = [thing1, thing2][0]

// individually they work
fn(thing1)
fn(thing2)

// Error: Property 'key2' is missing in type '{ key1: string; }' but required in type '{ key2: string; }'.
fn(eitherThing)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9GAEAuAWCmkBmBXAdgY2gSwPZsgEMAnAcxQFt41pJsBnOigB12OkJoBo6k7aA7oUYArFPVqdIuAEYj4WImUrVa2QbhQAbACaQBbANagM+CcgIBeSAB4AKpHgAPaNR2MA3gG1D8AJ4AXJASxNhopAC6QSFhpAC+AHwAFBiEWloyhBiGQUkkpEF2AJSQlgmQAG642DolZZDoOvBIYfA6oKAQdGg62BU1KGkwsLH0Jma0cLEAjKWQeWRBHr5+09HQoeFxdeWNza3tIKZo5lPhAExzCwWQy-7n65vxOw09+2htHeBQ6HgEuHx4OoEMRhrFxidaEC4PBiHYRuE5l4zqRpjwUecIl4AAwRL5dMK9fo6QbpPzDfz6IygJBoJIo6ZFGl0jFMkCdKAAUWIxDYQQACrzmLDoOSAOQrc5iuiMCgMeixbowPzCyBijyQFZrYIbWIAbkgcWlMhQtGI8AAjihsOa9GFlar1Zr7o99YaxQA6ZlJaEg+GxIpAA)

i have a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65727184/14809536) posted a while ago that i think conflated this and another issue. this question is more reduced and hopefully easier for someone to provide insight on. i still have no idea what legitimate reason there could be for union members to work individually but not as a union.

the only way i can get it to even kind of work is to change the generic to `T extends (arg: any) => void` and then extract the argument type from the function later to use for whatever, but the  `any` is important (for the reason explained by the [one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727184/why-cant-you-apply-a-union-of-things-to-a-generic-function-that-accepts-each-th#comment116238603_65727184) on my other question). i don't know how to do it and maintain any control over the shape of the argument.

edit: slightly more complicated example that doesn't work with the proposed solution using `Record` types [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKA9GAEAuAWCmkBmBXAdgY2gSwPZsgEMAnAcxQFt41pJsBnOigB12OkJoBo6k7aA7oUYArFPVqdIuAEYj4WImUrVa2QbhQAbACaQBbANagM+CcgIBeSAB4AKpHgAPaNR2MA3ofgBPAIwA-ABckB4A2t4+IRLE2GikALrR0LHxAL48kQBMwaERvsmpiYVxpGlpAHwAFBiEWloyhBiGIVUkpCF2AJSQlhWQAG642Do9fZDoOvBIcfA6oKAQdGg62AMjKHUwsKX0Jma0cKV+vZBtZCFevn6X9CgykSXpaWP9k9Oz8yCmaOZH8VlTucOqFsrd7o9IDFSuVXhMVh80HMFuAoOg8ARcHx4OoEMRtqV9r9aDi4PBiHYdvFTmF-qQ-Dw6VkEmEAAwJFFLOKrdY6Tb1HzbXz6IygJBoKp0vxdMUSpkykCLKAAUWIxDYIQACurmOToIKAOTZA10RgUBj0UrLGA+XWQA0eSCRG5QlKlADckDSJpkKFoxHgAEcUNgA3o4ja7Q6nb4sk9SJ7vQA6WVVUl4ymlLpAA)

edit2: i got excited about @jcalz tip about specifying the generic type, but i don't think its going to work for me, notes in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBvA1hEBGAfgC5MBtHEEgZ2ACcBLOAcwF1q7GmBfAGigoBMxMhXYNmbKDXHcuAbgCwAKGUBjAPZwaUAGZw0UADwAVKBAAewCHAAmVWAmQA+ABSqAhgBtPAI3eqsEhd3WiYSYwBKNCcoADd1ehso1BjEWwgdRggbZWUAejyoRht6WMTELyhgAAtOKjVNbRrOPANg0JJsXDxOqkQfUSkOZi4uZNT0zLhshq0UZuYBNpCwzEFe-sHpTlHxqDSbDKyclSUC-bh6TSh1HTN6GohaKtrmWe0IB+qn41emA1ICyYeD4QIELFIAAYWLkzoViqVyl5PCAXrgoAB3dS0LDKPQuIF4CJ4uAEv4CYmnc7Nez0expWgQLx04D0VS6bFQAC20GA6n4cHUGMx1Xc82+VF54Ag9hCEFBf1a7lsL04Swx9G8UB8EHyhUOU2yN2QVESvO+UA0cCslhud0e+1Znge9BlRQA5FzMdisJwbnA+OpHrQNZKPTZ9mHHnqLld9A9JZ47owoAADPSpqrSkmGLr4DYDXBiHZ8daYPqFyhDGSjVyfYO-TiUmP0O7K1G3NFhrE4o30d0RnVmcyqB4zJR6QzwJDAOtfH5-SmTjBcOcNxfKIA). basically the required type that you have to specify requires too much knowledge of the `thing` declarations.

edit3: based on jcalz's answer [this is where i ended up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-TxpNQD5man8MN6tvmlDukfQnBjaALKeJhphgeLBfQFexrOnyc4MhgagQMOtBztAEb4NA-DYLgEhqNAnb8iQ6CEFGbqwMIdzqG84hGtq1DKD8C4ghAmCYCGAGYGi5goOg9woKAuhIJmqEaIQsBqnyOphKAtz3OOlGAsYw6gAAog0+CHOAgaEK0tjnJCNR3msZT-JUL5vgAgp0B76f+gH4EOJSlNJmrGkpKn2DJckKXZGzgJUxTQPx-q2f87QWbAADCmAkBImAuW0kJjhOU4UMac5oCq1TWSR4WbMBOg0bRhjCpUQUhWF-z2Vs3kmv8gxAA)

Comment: Can I ask what you would imagine the correct inference for `T` should be? I think typescript may be right here. Note that for any types `A` and `B` (where neither `A` nor `B` is a subtype of the other) the types `(arg: A | B) => void` and `((arg: A) => void) | ((arg: B) => void)` are describing quite different things.

Comment: the point is that either thing can legitimately be applied to the function, since the union type represents any one of the things, why can't it be applied too? @CRice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short version: you *can* pass a union of functions info `fn()` but you will need to manually specify a value of `T` that works, because the compiler balks when it finds multiple candidates for `T`, and produces an error rather than combining them, because often multiple candidates are indicative of developer error.

Long version:

---

First, you *can* pass a union of functions into `fn()`, but the compiler will not infer the necessary specification of type parameter `T` for you automatically.  First of all, what *should* `T` be?

You don't know (or at least the compiler doesn't) whether `eitherThing` accepts a `{key1: string}` or a `{key2: string}`.  The only safe thing to call it with is something that's *both*: `{key1: string} & {key2: string}` or equivalently `{key1: string; key2: string}`; that is, a *union* of functions requires an *intersection* of arguments.  This is a result of the *contravariance* of functions in their parameter types.  See [this documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) for how TypeScript interprets calling unions-of-functions as requiring intersections-of-arguments.

So, let's try it:

```
fn<{ key1: string, key2: string }>(eitherThing); // okay
```

Yep, that works!  So `fn()` can indeed be called with `eitherThing`, as long as you treat `T` as the *intersection* of the arguments for `thing1` and `thing2`.

---

Of course the question now is "why doesn't the compiler infer a type for `T` if it's possible for there to be one?"  The canonical answer to that is probably to be found in [microsoft/TypeScript#40665](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40665).  The heuristics used by the compiler to infer generic type parameters are the way they are because they enable common use cases and flag common errors.  If there are multiple dissimilar candidates for a generic type parameter, such as your `{key1: string}` and `{key2: string}` for `T`, the compiler will often decide that this is probably an error.

Let's look at this generic function:

```
function either<T>(a: T, b: T) {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? a : b;
}

either(1, 2); // okay
either("three", "four"); // okay
either(5, "six"); // error!
```

Here `either()` takes two values `a` and `b` of the same type and returns one of them.  But what does "of the same type" mean?  Most people would expect `either(5, "six")` to fail because `5` is a  `number` and `"six"` is a `string`. And the compiler does produce an error there.

But it is *conceivable* that someone could expect the compiler to infer `number | string` for `T` here, since both `5` and `"six"` are `number | string` values.  But that would imply that `either()` could *never* error no matter what crazy things you put in there: `either("hello", () => 1)` would work, or `either(23, Date)`, etc.  If you think it's possible for developers to make mistakes when calling generic functions, and you think sometimes the compiler should issue errors, then this sort of tradeoff is inevitable.

See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40665#issuecomment-696377093):

> inferring a [more general type] *was* the behavior until TypeScript 1.4 and we got bug reports complaining about it practically daily because it makes it nearly impossible for a generic call to be rejected.

And so you have a similar issue here:

```
either(thing1, thing1); // okay
either(thing1, thing2); // error!
```

Here again there are two candidates for `T`: `(arg: {key1: string}) => undefined)` and `(arg: {key2: string}) => undefined`.  Rather than combine them into a single candidate that works, the compiler assumes this is an error.

And the same thing happens with your original call to `fn()`. There are two candidates for `T`: `{key1: string}`, and `{key2: string}`.  And rather than combine them into a single candidate, the compiler assumes this is an error.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=7&pln=13&pc=8#code/LAKA9GAEAuAWCmkBmBXAdgY2gSwPZsgEMAnAcxQFt41pJsBnOigB12OkJoBo6k7aA7oUYArFPVqdIuAEYj4WImUrVa2QbhQAbACaQBbANagM+CcgIBeSAB4AKpHgAPaNR2MA3pADah+AE8ALkgJYmw0UgBdYNDw0kgAXwA+AAoMQi0tGUIMQ2CUklJguwBKSEskyAA3XGwdMorIdB14JHD4HVBQCDo0HWwqupQMmFg4+hMzWjg4gEZyyAKyYK8-f1mY6DCIxIbK5tb2zpBTNHMZiIAmBaWiyFWAy83t+IS9pr7DtA6u8Ch0PAEXB8eDqBDEUZxSZnWiguDwYh2MY7azeC6kWY8dGXSLeAAMkV+PXC-UGOmGmX8owC+iMoCQaBS6NmJXpjOxrJAbJsD3WzziPDWTxCWziiVScPBSLinPp6CwgMcYIR9lShGKPBkxTKHlAkH1kGI8GgKGIBAAsoQ4AA6YicHS4CgpMo2SB460AVkgAH4iJBgjIANygBKgSUIlKYyCXEqByA9XCGQj+MPK4gpABEcCN8AzPAzSE0xAzsfjUETydT8PTHvz9GwThLcZ6COIbAAhL9w+nmVjkRjSwmkymQN2mf2oxzm1BWx3QEA)

Comment: i guess my expectation is that the generic constraints be evaluated for each member separately not all together, since the value will be one of the members not some mashup. i added an edit with some thoughts about your tip about specifying the generic type.

Comment: "the value will be one of the members not some mashup."  Right, but there's just one `T`, and the choice of `T` that corresponds to "one of the members" is precisely the intersection. That's not "some mashup", it's what happens to unions in contravariant positions.  As for whether you can or can't write out the intersection manually, there are ways of teasing the proper `T` out of the compiler without having to write it yourself, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/oN5D5w).  But if you don't agree that `T` should be the intersection, I'm curious as to what you think it should be instead.

Comment: I'm expecting some kind of split processing of the union members, generating different T values for each and then zip the return values up in another union. I can see how this is kind of unreasonable especially with the indirect relationship between T and the function arguments and if there were more than one union argument, etc... It's just confusing because i can see them working individually and I feel like it should work on an array, but I can see where the compiler issues are coming from now

Comment: I'm using the first technique specifying the generic term when calling it for now, i like that it keeps the function types more simple. although I still have a use case for passing the function with the props to call it as described in my other question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65727184/14809536 and i'm struggling to apply new new knowledge to make that work again... maybe if you had time you could take a look at that one. you'd have accepted answers for all three of my SO questions ever so that'd be cool

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have named keys so the arg objects no longer fit the shape of `{[key: string]: string}`. Can you not do something like this where you pass the specific shape at the time of declaration?

```
type Callback<T = Record<string, string>> = (arg: T) => void;
type Func<T = Record<string, string>> = (callback: Callback<T>) => void;

// the function argument is important, if it was just an object argument it would work
const fn: Func = (callback) => undefined;

// individual things
const thing1: Callback<Record<'key1', string>> = (arg) => undefined
const thing2: Callback<Record<'key2', string>> = (arg) => undefined

// union of either thing
const eitherThing = [thing1, thing2][0]

// individually they work
fn(thing1)
fn(thing2)

// and here they work too
fn(eitherThing)
```

Comment: this only works with this super basic case though right? the record types can't handle a more complicated interface that has different keys with potentially different values? i edited an example into my question

Comment: Sure, but if you're expecting to deal with various complicated shapes then why not use `unknown` and pass in the correct type at the time? FWIW I was still able to solve your "more complicated" playground code in that way. It's not very clear what your specific constraints are.

Comment: Maybe I could have been more clear in my post but I do want to maintain some control over the overall shape of the argument, it's just not as simple as a consistent key and value type. If I wanted to sling some `unknown`s around the whole problem would be a non-issue, I think I gave a working example using `any`